# Can the nextjs image sizes prop value be in pixels?

Tags: next.js, nextjs-image

**sizes**

A string, similar to a media query, that provides information about how wide the image will be at different breakpoints. The value of sizes will greatly affect performance for images using fill or which are styled to have a responsive size.

`<Image src={cover} fill={true} sizes="(max-width: 700px) 30vw, 80px"/>`
Sizes prop doesn't work if the values are in pixels

Can anyone specify the reason?

Answer (score 0):

The sizes prop in the Next.js Image component should be specified in a format that's similar to a media query, not in fixed pixels. This is because it's intended to help the browser determine which image source to load based on the viewport width and the screen's pixel density.

In your example, you're using (max-width: 700px) 30vw, 80px, which is indeed the correct format for the sizes prop. Here's what it means:

- (max-width: 700px) 30vw: When the viewport width is at most 700 pixels, the image's width will be 30% of the viewport width.
- 80px: For all other cases (viewport width greater than 700 pixels), the image width will be a fixed 80 pixels.
  This approach allows the browser to load appropriately sized images for different screen sizes and resolutions, which can greatly improve performance.

If you specify values in fixed pixels (e.g., 100px), it essentially tells the browser to always load an image that's 100 pixels wide, regardless of the screen size or DPR. This defeats the purpose of responsive images and can result in larger image files being loaded than necessary for smaller screens or lower DPRs, negatively impacting performance.

So, it's recommended to use the format (max-width: ...) ... in the sizes prop to ensure that the browser loads the most appropriate image for the user's device and viewport size.